# Ecoboost 3.5L Twin-Turbo reliability

Tags: engine, ford, explorer

I'm looking for a $15,000 SUV to pull my 4,000-lb travel trailer, and I really like the Ford Explorer. I've been looking at some used 2014 Ford Explorer Sport vehicles with ~100,000-125,000 miles on them, but am concerned about the reliability of Ecoboost Twin-Turbo engines.

**Ecoboost Twin-Turbo longevity:** Is there much life left in a 125,000-mile 3.5L Ecoboost, especially if I'm going to be stressing it a lot near the tow limit of 5,000 lbs?

**Twin-Turbo Ecoboost vs. non-Turbo towing capacity:**
I understand that the Twin Turbo Ecoboost 3.5L V6 in the Explorer Sport generates more torque than the 3.5L non-turbo AWD XLT model with the tow package, but while both are rated to 5,000 lbs (2014 version here) does that mean one is better than the other?

I read some raving reviews online about the Ecoboost, but depending on the mechanic I talk to I get a very different picture.

Comment: Take a coin and decide heads or tails... if it has been properly serviced and maintained it could be good for donkeys years - if not it may last years or not.

Answer (score 1):

Towing two tons with a 4,900 lbs. vehicle?  You are asking for big trouble.  I don't care what the "rated" towing capacity is.  Witness, for example, the recent death of [the daughter](https://www.wlbt.com/2020/06/14/daughter-hank-williams-jr-reportedly-killed-vehicle-crash/) of Hank Williams, Jr., who died in an SUV while towing a boat.  That year Explorer has also just been recalled for rear suspension failures, which could cause "a sudden change in vehicle handling and increase the [risk of a crash](https://cars.usnews.com/cars-trucks/ford/explorer/2014/reliability)."  I've personally towed a 20-foot boat weighing less than half what you are proposing, and it was not easy.  Watch a few YouTube videos and you will see what can happen!  Unless you have a lot of professional experience towing, I would scrap the whole idea and get a different type of vehicle.